# selenium2.0 how to deal with unusual problems

Tags: java, selenium, exception, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Beginner selenium2.0 ask you heroes throw exception when the web page. selenium2.0 is how to capture and handle page exception?

I do not want to stop and let the entire testing process because of unusual problems. Is there a scene like qtp restore function? if we usually encounter this exception problem is how to solve...

thank you!!

Comment: Can you give an example of the 'unusual' problems you mean? The exceptions are thrown for a reason, one reason you would want to catch the exception is to rethrow it with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [Oracle Java Tutorial about Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

The short answer is that all WebDriver methods throw particular types of `Exceptions` which you can catch and handle.

```
WebElement elem = null;
try {
    elem = driver.findElement(By.id("someId"));
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage());
    throw e;    // or not if this error was expected, program then continues
}
```